# How to Show category and sub category hierarchy tree in nodejs and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, express

My Schema:
{name,slug,parentId}

My expected output is :

```
{
  id:61d0983e656c00e7cb0441c5,
  name:"Programing",
  parentId:null,
  clildren:[
   {
     id:61d0990ba60d4408732bb595,
     name:"Java",
     parentId:61d0983e656c00e7cb0441c5,
     subCate:[
           {
            id:61d099b1ed4ac943623cb28d,
            name:"Project",
            parentId:61d0990ba60d4408732bb595,
            subCate:[]
           }
         ]
   }
  ]
}
```

how to get this type of result.

Comment: What do you mean of type of result ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?